# SSL SQOOP CONNECTION WITH AS400

Tags: ssl, sqoop, ibm-midrange

I am looking for a way to make an secured SSL connection with as400 while using Sqoop
Below is the syntax I am using and please suggest modifications to make it secured connection

```
sqoop import \
–driver com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver \
–connect jdbc:as400://as400servername/dbname \
–username xxxxxxxx –password xxxxxxxx \
–query ‘SELECT * FROM <table_name> where $CONDITIONS’ \
–hive-import \
–hive-table table_name \
–target-dir /user/hdfs/example \
–fields-terminated-by ’01’ \
–split-by <id> \
-m 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `secure` property for the [JDBC driver](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/doc/com/ibm/as400/access/doc-files/JDBCProperties.html)

so I guess you should just need

```
-secure true \
```

If you're intending to use a key ring, there's a couple additional properties to set.

Comment: i am getting an error as Unrecognized argument : -secure true

Comment: I am not familiar with Sqoop, sorry can't be more specific